# Adding Google Image search button to Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create an e-shop and I want to redirect customers to google images to see photos of the produc (if there are). How can I retrieve the product sku and provide a button which directs (in a new tab) customers to google images search results by that sku?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google Image search can be done on your page by going through this tutorial on Google's website [TUTORIAL](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide)

As far as retrieving the product SKU, that depends how you saved the product SKU in the database. If you are talking about the manufacturer's barcode, I don't think you can just magically come up with that. You should save the barcode in a custom field for each product in your database, then call the custom field using the `Wordpress` function `get_post_meta`